# How to save and restore the selection of a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using a Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control as a text editor. To alter the font size of some selected Text, I display a modal window, where the user can make chices concerning the font size and after closing that window, the previously selected text is decorated with the changes. Unfortunately as soon as the modal window opens, the selection in the main windows isn´t visible anymore and I can´t find a way to save and restore it. I can determine the selected Range using

```
    IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
    IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = htmlDocument.selection;
```

but since `htmlDocument.selection`is readonly, I am not able to set it after the modal closes. All I Can do is call `Select()` on the main window, but then the caret jumps to the end of the text and nothing is selected.

Any ideas how to solve this? 
(I know I could use a ComboBox to alter Font-size, but I need the custom window...for reasons.)

Comment: In your code to launch the dialog box, could you determine the location of the change prior to opening the window and save that somewhere.  Then have the callback from the dialog box closing read the stored location and commit the change.

Comment: The built-in editor feature in Internet Explorer is quite notorious.  The MSDN forums tried repeatedly to tame it and always failed miserably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bookmarks. Save selection as bookmark:

```
var bookmark = document.selection.createRange().getBookmark();
```

Restore:

```
var range = document.selection.createRange();
range.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
range.select();
```

Comment: Great idea and wokrs well. Result of createRange must be cast to "IHTMLTxtRange" to use bookmark-methods. Unfortunately, in some cases I get a COMException with error code -2147467259 when trying to restore the bookmark.